# Why isn't localhost working?

Tags: xampp, localhost

I installed XAMPP and I've gone into the htdocs file and opened the index.html file but this is the address of where it takes me: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.html. I thought that it should be a localhost file and not a file:///C:/ file. This message appears when I open the file though: It works! Is this normal? Also when I try to open the index.php file in the htdocs folder it just opens the file in my text editor instead of my browser. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into your adress bar and put in

```
localhost/index.html
```

do `localhost` and it will bring you to your default or index

Then it will bring you all the files you have in that folder

If you want to get to phpmyadmin for you databases, you would to

```
localhost/phpmyadmin
```

I hope this helps

ps. mame sure xampp is running "apache".

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers use a number of different [schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) to indicate how to get the resource.  By clicking on a file, you're implicitly using the `file:` scheme.  What you really want is the `http:` scheme.  The way to do that is to enter `http://localhost` into the browser of your choice and it will actually ask XAMPP to serve the file, rather than just using the operating system's file mechanism.

Also if you click on a file in Windows and it opens up an editor, it's because you have an association of that file extension to that particular application.  To learn how to change that, read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859